# WSDL Error: Document could not be read at line 0

Tags: java, wsdl

I am having an issue with a WSDL that no one else around me seems to be having. This is even stumping my instructor. When you copy and paste the body of the WSDL into a new file and then rename it to `CostService.wsdl` it works, but as soon as you do anything to the project the error below occurs. This is the exact same file as everyone else in my class uses, but only I have this issue. Can anyone help to point me in the right direction? Thank you!

> The WSDL document
>   file:///workspace/CostService/config/CostService.wsdl could not be
>   read. CostService.wsdl /CostService/config line 0 - WSDL Problem

Comment: what framework or library do you use? What IDE?

Comment: maybe it's encoding problem and when you copy-paste is fixed because of some 'default' encoding conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure that I should let people know my resolution in case they have the same problem. It seems as though it was a corrupted work space or eclipse environment... I deleted the environment and work space and started all over again. It seems to be alright now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me before. Open your WSDL in a file editor that shows "hidden" characters and look for an ASCII character that is probably before your opening < character. Delete this and save the file and you should be fine.

Comment: No such luck. I tried opening it in Notepad, Word, and Notepad++. According to Internet Explorer and my instructor, the file is a well formed XML file as well. Thank you though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you try jEdit? http://www.jedit.org/ That's where I think I found what was messing mine up, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just gave that a shot and it didn't work. Nothing was before the first <.

Comment: Well now.....um...I guess you could try to copy the file outside of the IDE and then import it into the IDE and see what happens (this would validate an IDE error of sorts). Otherwise another thought would be to read out the contents of the file using a FileInputStream just to see if there is something there, but the first two should have proved that. Maybe try to copy the file outside of the IDE and see if it is an IDE bug.

Comment: I attempted using a new workspace and re-installing my JDK with no luck.

Comment: Is this eclipse? have you looked at any of your IDE logs to see what it is complaining about? Perhaps a bug or an old plugin?